# HTML5 Mobile App Shows Double Select Options

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm wondering if anyone has had this issue also? I have a HTML5 Mobile app that works fine in the browser, but since 2 days ago, on my android, when I hit the drop down select element, the options appear as expected, but when I select one and the list hides, I see another list of the same options behind it. This only started happening after the update of android to 5.1.1 a couple of days ago, but I'm not sure why that would cause it.

I'm still in the process of testing with a new HTML5 app to determine whether the issue can be replicated, but if you have come across this also, please let me know.

Paul

---

```html
<h3>Item Class</h3> 
<div class="form-control-group">
  <div class="form-control form-control-select required"> 
    <select name="item_class" 
            class="element inputField" 
            id="item_class_selector"
            data-property="Item_Class__c" 
            onchange="getSuppliers(this[this.selectedIndex].text, 'supplier_selector')">
    </select>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please post some HTML code which reproduces this issue.

Comment: Here is the HTML: 

<h3>Item Class</h3>
<div class="form-control-group">
<div class="form-control form-control-select required">
  <select name="item_class" class="element inputField" id="item_class_selector" data-property="Item_Class__c" onchange="getSuppliers(this[this.selectedIndex].text, 'supplier_selector')"></select>
 </div>
</div>